# PHP Code- How to check duplicate entries in Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on Google checkout API notification URL. I want to apply a check in my php code which will see if transaction ID present in transaction table of my DB, it will exit not process.

I am struggling into applying here. Can somebody help?

I want to check if trasaction ID exists in table of DB it will exit, it will not process:

```
case "new-order-notification":  
    $sql = "
        UPDATE
            transactions
        SET
            remote_trans_id=\"".$_REQUEST["google-order-number"]."\", updated=NOW() 
        WHERE
        id=".$_REQUEST["shopping-cart_items_item-1_merchant-item-id"]
        ;
    execute($sql, $conn);
break;
```

Regards

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi pekka, i want to insert a check before code, if transaction id exists in DB than code will exit, it will not process it twice. case "new-order-notification":    

            // Update transaction
            $sql = "update
                        transactions
                    set
                        remote_trans_id=\"".$_REQUEST["google-order-number"]."\", updated=now() 
                    where
                        id=".$_REQUEST["shopping-cart_items_item-1_merchant-item-id"]."
                    ";
            execute($sql, $conn);
            break;

Comment: set the index to unique for the id

Comment: @Grumpy: IMO should be an answer

Comment: as a general suggestion dont use $_REQUEST variables directly into your SQL. Use PDO parameter binding and filter your params before. This is a security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). This way mySql will do the checking for you, if is a new transaction will enter it otherwise will update the existing entry.

Answer (score 0):

set the index to unique for the id

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid double processing when a user hits the refresh or back button on their browser, there may be a better way to handle this.

In the top of your script, create a temp uniqid in a session variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['temp_page_instance'] = uniqid();
```

Then, in your form, create a hidden input called page_instance, which will equal the temp_page_instance.

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_instance" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['temp_page_instance']; ?>" />
```

Then, at the bottom of your script set the actual page instance.

```
$_SESSION['page_instance'] = $_SESSION['temp_page_instance'];
```

In the logic that processes the form data, put a check in there that makes sure your $_POST['page_instance'] == $_SESSION['page_instance']. If not, the page has been reloaded, and it should not process the form again.

Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

You can select all the id's, place them in a an associative array (and maybe save it in a file with serialize instead of always going to the table) like:

```
$all_ids =  array(
    'id1' => 1, 
    'id2' => 1,
    etc..
```

Then when you want to check if an id exists you just to

```
if (isset($all_ids[$id])) { ... }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: And what's wrong with just doing a "SELECT ... WHERE ... id=google_order_number" and seeing if anything's returned? Selecting an entire table of IDs just to do a single isset() is highly inefficient.

Comment: @Marc B: This is for future times. Instead of selecting everytime just have in cache an array with the values.